# Display label on error (HTML CSS)

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, label

I try to show a label when there is wrong information. For this i try this code:

C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
    }
    catch( Exception )
    {
        Label1.Text = ("Wrong info");
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.info {
    border-color:#F7281E;  
    background-color:#F8D8D7;
    color: #ec3309;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" class="info" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

When i try above code and then when i try wrong info in text box then label is not display how i display the label ?

When i remove `display:none` then background with this color `#F7281E;` is display on page

any solution?

Comment: where is css & html problem? use another tags

Comment: Why do you need the `display:none` if the label doesn't have any content when the page starts? If removing it solves the issue, do other issues remain?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov What do you think the problem is then? This is clearly a css problem.

Comment: i can solve this problem on html & css, but u code is something else

Comment: @MrLister when i remove display:none then the problem is when i open page then background color is display

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the Label by default by setting its `Visible` property to `false`:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" class="info" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

and make it visible when necessary:

```
catch( Exception )
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Wrong info";
}
```

For that to work, you should remove `display: none;` from the CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

Remove background color from CSS and apply through code.

**In code :**

`Label1.BackColor = '#F8D8D7';`

**In CSS**

```
.info{
    border-color:#F7281E;  
    color: #ec3309;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: on page load or on button click ?

Comment: when i apply this on button click this show error .. Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Color'

Comment: I think it's better to apply a special class to the label, rather than one of the css properties. In this case, you also have the padding taking up space.

Comment: special class ?? how i apply

Comment: You can apply as per the requirement. If you want that color in the initial stage then go with DOM ready or onload. 

You can also use an additional class(with background color) instead of applying style directly as said by @MrLister.